# SSRS - My row filter code is correct but is not being applied

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a row filter on a table in SSRS.

My formula looks as follows:

[image]

I have the exact same formula pasted into the "Show" column below:

[image]

It doesn't matter what I try, "IsNothing() = true", "Len=0", "CDBl(number + 10) = 0"; "IsNothing(TextBox20) = true"
The entire dataset comes back. I only want to show items that are in my one dataset, but do not exist in another.
I've tried creating a group with my results set (as per a stack overflow solution), but nothing seems to work. Either the entire dataset is returned or none of it. I only want the "Show=true" rows to be returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When having problems with a filter expression like this, I usually change the expression to return 1 or 0, set the **TYPE** to **INTEGER** and put **1** (or 0) in the **Value**. **=IIF(ISNOTHING(blah blah), 1, 0)** I noticed problems when using BOOLEAN. You can also try putting your expression in a text box and see what the result is. I assume that your field in NULL and not blank ('').

Comment: I've tried that as well :(